# Accessing global variable in UI handler Google Spreadsheet Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a simple, but import question.

I have declared a global variable in my script (Google Spreadsheet Script). Next I am calling a UI application from the SS Script. It has a listbox and a button. It shows fine.

When I click the button, it should put the selected value to the global variable. Problem is inside the handler function (click(eventInfo)), it does not recognise the global variable (SELNAME). How can I overcome this?

```
//global variable
var SELNAME; 

function show() {
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('My Application');
var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
var lb = app.createListBox(true).setId('myId').setName('myLbName');


// add items to ListBox
lb.setVisibleItemCount(8);

lb.addItem("one");
lb.addItem("two");
lb.addItem("three");

panel.add(lb);
var button = app.createButton('press me');
var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('click').addCallbackElement(panel);
button.addClickHandler(handler);
panel.add(button);
app.add(panel);
doc.show(app);
}


function click(eventInfo) {
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
// get values of ListBox
var value = eventInfo.parameter.myLbName;
// multi select box returns a comma separated string
var n = value.split(',');

var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

SELNAM =value;

return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have with this global variable is not (only) related to handler functions.

Global variables in Google Apps Script **can not be modified** from within a function, they can only be read as constants.

Bad news ? not really since there are a lot of possible workarounds...

One possible way to get the expected behavior is to use [scriptProperties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/script-properties) to store the "global" value (or useProperties from the same service if you want that this value remains private to you)

Outside of your function you can assign a value to your key like this :

```
ScriptProperties.setProperty(key, value);
```

and then in any function where you need to access or modify it simply use this :

```
var value = ScriptProperties.getProperty(key);// to get the value
// do something with that value...
ScriptProperties.setProperty(key, value);// to update the value
```

There are of course other workaround like [hidden widgets in the Ui](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/hidden) but this one has many advantages, the first one IMHO is that you can easily see the value from the script editor (*File/project properties/project properties*) while debuging.

Comment: ScriptProperties Class is now **deprecated**.

Comment: indeed... replace with PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty(key,value)