# Simple Google script query on Spreadsheet takes too long due to unwanted calls

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I need to get data from the active cell of a Google Spreadsheet. The script to request the data so far is quite simple:

```
function getSelectedRow(){

  Logger.log("Looking up active row...")
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetValues(cell.getRow(), 1, 1, 20);
  Logger.log(data)
}
```

However, running the script takes a long time. Although the execution transcript shows:

```
[14-10-17 11:25:56:480 ICT] Execution succeeded [0.668 seconds total runtime]
```

It paradoxically shows a start time 36 second before:

```
[14-10-17 11:25:19:145 ICT] Starting execution
```

In fact, the first log occurs at a time matching with the claimed execution time:

```
[14-10-17 11:25:55:811 ICT] Logger.log([Looking up active row..., []]) [0 seconds]
```

Yet between the start time and this first log, the following occurs:

```
[14-10-17 11:25:19:175 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() [0 seconds]
[14-10-17 11:25:19:326 ICT] Sheet.getDataRange() [0.15 seconds]
[14-10-17 11:25:22:210 ICT] Range.getValues() [2.882 seconds]
[14-10-17 11:25:22:241 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() [0 seconds]
[14-10-17 11:25:22:371 ICT] Sheet.getDataRange() [0.13 seconds]
[14-10-17 11:25:25:407 ICT] Range.getValues() [3.034 seconds]
[14-10-17 11:25:25:442 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() [0 seconds]
[14-10-17 11:25:25:612 ICT] Sheet.getDataRange() [0.169 seconds]
[14-10-17 11:25:28:369 ICT] Range.getValues() [2.756 seconds]
[14-10-17 11:25:28:408 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() [0 seconds]
[14-10-17 11:25:28:541 ICT] Sheet.getDataRange() [0.133 seconds]
[14-10-17 11:25:31:407 ICT] Range.getValues() [2.865 seconds]
[14-10-17 11:25:31:439 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() [0 seconds]
[14-10-17 11:25:31:571 ICT] Sheet.getDataRange() [0.131 seconds]
[14-10-17 11:25:34:313 ICT] Range.getValues() [2.741 seconds]
[14-10-17 11:25:34:346 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() [0 seconds]
[14-10-17 11:25:34:500 ICT] Sheet.getDataRange() [0.153 seconds]
[14-10-17 11:25:37:357 ICT] Range.getValues() [2.856 seconds]
[14-10-17 11:25:37:387 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() [0 seconds]
[14-10-17 11:25:37:526 ICT] Sheet.getDataRange() [0.138 seconds]
[14-10-17 11:25:40:293 ICT] Range.getValues() [2.766 seconds]
[14-10-17 11:25:40:325 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() [0 seconds]
[14-10-17 11:25:40:478 ICT] Sheet.getDataRange() [0.152 seconds]
[14-10-17 11:25:43:509 ICT] Range.getValues() [3.031 seconds]
[14-10-17 11:25:43:543 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() [0 seconds]
[14-10-17 11:25:43:690 ICT] Sheet.getDataRange() [0.146 seconds]
[14-10-17 11:25:46:523 ICT] Range.getValues() [2.832 seconds]
[14-10-17 11:25:46:558 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() [0 seconds]
[14-10-17 11:25:46:689 ICT] Sheet.getDataRange() [0.13 seconds]
[14-10-17 11:25:49:363 ICT] Range.getValues() [2.673 seconds]
[14-10-17 11:25:49:404 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() [0 seconds]
[14-10-17 11:25:49:538 ICT] Sheet.getDataRange() [0.133 seconds]
[14-10-17 11:25:52:571 ICT] Range.getValues() [3.033 seconds]
[14-10-17 11:25:52:606 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() [0 seconds]
[14-10-17 11:25:52:756 ICT] Sheet.getDataRange() [0.149 seconds]
[14-10-17 11:25:55:774 ICT] Range.getValues() [3.016 seconds]
```

So basically, the script effectively takes a long time to run because it keeps making calls to the spreadsheet. I don't know what's causing those calls to be made, there is no call I made other than the one in question in the function.

Can you help me understand and solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you have some spreadsheet calls that are outside of the function you show, some sort of "global variable" that uses `Sheet.getDataRange()`and `Range.getValues()` somewhere...

these "outside" calls run when any function is called and that's what you see in the execution transcript.

Clean up your code or wrap these calls into a function and you'll get an execution transcript as below :

```
[14-10-17 09:16:12:921 CEST] Starting execution
[14-10-17 09:16:12:941 CEST] Logger.log([Looking up active row..., []]) [0 seconds]
[14-10-17 09:16:12:941 CEST] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() [0 seconds]
[14-10-17 09:16:12:942 CEST] Sheet.getActiveCell() [0 seconds]
[14-10-17 09:16:12:943 CEST] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() [0 seconds]
[14-10-17 09:16:12:943 CEST] Range.getRow() [0 seconds]
[14-10-17 09:16:13:048 CEST] Sheet.getSheetValues([1, 1, 1, 20]) [0.104 seconds]
[14-10-17 09:16:13:049 CEST] Logger.log([[[0.0, xxx0, some values here, some values there, another one, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ]], []]) [0 seconds]
[14-10-17 09:16:13:050 CEST] Execution succeeded [0.108 seconds total runtime]
```

Comment: Ah yes, correct! I'm guilty as charged: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26352289/global-variable-defined-in-function-appears-not-defined
I was too stubborn made a call each time I looked up a header index, instead of looking up the header row once and extracting the header indexes. Now we're down to about 4 seconds. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See if this modified code runs faster

```
function getSelectedRow(){

  Logger.log("Looking up active row...")
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange(sheet.getActiveCell().getRow(), 1, 1, 20).getValues();
  Logger.log(data)
}
```

Comment: Nope. The same problem occurs again. Thanks for trying.

Comment: How is this function called? By user from add-on/menu or by script from a trigger/another function?